# Salesforce currency field decimal rounding, too many decimal places

Tags: currency

How come my currency field numbers are slightly off from the whole numbers? 
for example

8.90000000000003

23.34999999999997

40.8199999999999

I recall having to do something to prevent this from happening but I'm sure that I did not input them as 8.90000000000000000000000000000003

Comment: It might occur due to the nature of how numbers are being stored - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: were the fields computed using some arithmetic operator such as * or / ? If so, the apex or flow/PB/WF formula should use setScale/rounding before assigning to the field